# Replace some of a matched string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a grid layout function. I'm about 1/2 way there and have hit a wall.

I am using a string and running a single RegExp function per box I'm placing in the grid to determine where it will fit (based on number of rows/columns it occupies). This works successfully. Demonstration:

```
function findSpace(columns, rows){
    var totalColumns = 4;
    var grid = "11002100020000200002";
    //1 represents occupied space, 0 empty space, and 2 a new line
    var reg = RegExp("(0{" + columns + "})(([0-2]{" + (totalColumns - columns + 1) + "})0{"+columns+"}){" + (rows-1) + "}");
    var i = grid.search(reg);
    return i.index;
}
```

Returns the index of the match, letting me know where in my grid this box will fall. See [fiddle.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/F5Tqs/1/)

I fall short trying to replace the "0"s with "1"s. Doing `grid.replace(reg, "1")` of course replaces everything from the beginning of the match to the end with a single "1". I need to replace just the "0"s that will be occupied for row and column, each with a "1", and not any of the characters matched between.

This is an exercise in doing things differently. Yes, I could do this with an array data structure. What fun is that? I'm not looking for a "don't do it this way do it the way everyone else does" answer, I'm trying to determine the most efficient way to solve my scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String#replace` method might be the ticket. If you pass a regular expression and a function as the second parameter, you can dynamically manipulate each match.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: That just might be the ticket, it's a good thought. I'll work on it and get back to you.